# Hide results of drupal view when filter value is empty after search

Tags: 7, views

Help needed, how to hide all results of a view when filter value is empty, after search button pressed.

(I have this: Set Advanced | Exposed Form | Exposed Form Style to input required. Not working well. When open view OK, but for empty search field, and search button pressed all appear)

I know there are lot of solutions  here: (5 years old) https://www.drupal.org/node/358546 but I can't find those options in views in Drupal 7.

Can somone provide a working solution for Drupal 7 and Views version 7.x-3.x?

[image]
Explain question, end the operator for VIN and kod sterownika set to: "is equal to"

Comment: +1 upvote and added Drupal 9 tag because this answer here [this answer on tis page here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/127975/10820). Note to moderators: when more than one supported Drupal version is tagged on a question, this can lead to the thinking to be removing all tags, if the questions and answers apply to all. But in this case I am thinking there are a mixture of distinct Drupal version specific answers, mainly 7, to warrant both tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok till someone provide better solution

I create this one, and it's working :) It is important that i heave "is equal to" in VIN search field, so when I inject "X" as a value, if there is no conditions this will solve my problem.

```
function hook_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {

  if ($view->name == 'my_view_name') {

      //print_r($query);
      if (!isset($query->where[1]['conditions'][0] ))
      {
           $query->where[1]['conditions'][0] = array(
                                'field' => 'guarantee.vin',
                                'value' => 'X',
                                'operator' =>'LIKE' 
                            );
      }
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Edit your view and then set the "Exposed form style" to basic.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Hope that helps!

Comment: I have like that, but this is good for open new fresh view, there will be no rows. When you will press "search" and you will have empty filter fields, your view will return all rows...I need to return nothing till filter field is empty

Comment: On the last image above just check the "Include reset button" checklist. Now when someone wants to go back to empty filters they will click the reset button. This should take them back to the view as it starts out. If configure like the rest of the images above it will start back at empty.

Comment: We probably do not understand well. I do not want the search results if the search field is empty. To explain this please do view on users entity, provide search field by email. Please set everything as showed on the pictures, then press the search button, and you will see all users as a result... And I wanted empty result until someone type part of the email in the filter field

Comment: Ok, sorry about the misunderstanding. I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: +1 upvote on this answer - thank you - the config setting change described is also in Drupal 9, 9.3.12. I have found this to work, whereby no results are shown if filter is initially empty. This suits my need well, whereby I am implementing a search solution based around Views and exposed filter without the need for search, indexing, solr etc - all have merit of course but this Views-exposed filter solution is simpler and works well for what I need for now. Thank you again.

Comment: Have raised issue on better exposed filters to provide similar "no results": https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters/issues/3280768